# How to create a directory in Live Server using PHP?

Tags: php, windows, cakephp

```
<?php
$dirPath = "Admin/new_images";
$result = mkdir($dirPath, 0777);
if ($result == 1) {
echo $dirPath . " has been created";
} else {
    echo $dirPath . " has NOT been created";
}
?>
```

This code is working fine with my Local Host.
But its not working on live server.
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: get a dump from `__DIR__` to check whether you are in a correct path or not?

Comment: are you working on window?

Comment: yes we are working on windows

Comment: try with `$dirPath = "Admin\\new_images";`

Comment: change : mkdir($dirPath); => for mode is ignored on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
$dirPath = "Admin/new_images";
$result = mkdir($dirPath, 0777, true);
chmod($dirPath, 0777); 

if ($result == 1) {
echo $dirPath . " has been created";
} else {
    echo $dirPath . " has NOT been created";
}
?>
```

for window u have to change `$dirPath` like below:

```
$dirPath = "Admin\\new_images";
```

Answer (score 0):

mkdir — Makes directory

Description

```
bool mkdir ( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive = false [, resource $context ]]] )
```

Attempts to create the directory specified by pathname.

**Parameters :**

> pathname  The directory path.
>
> mode  The mode is 0777 by default, which means the widest possible
>   access. For more information on modes, read the details on the chmod()
>   page.
>
> Note:
>
> mode is ignored on Windows.
>
> Note that you probably want to specify the mode as an octal number,
>   which means it should have a leading zero. The mode is also modified
>   by the current umask, which you can change using umask().
>
> recursive  Allows the creation of nested directories specified in the
>   pathname. Defaults to FALSE.
>
> context  Note: Context support was added with PHP 5.0.0. For a
>   description of contexts, refer to Stream Functions

**Return Values**

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

```
<?php

/**
 * Makes directory, returns TRUE if exists or made
 *
 * @param string $pathname The directory path.
 * @return boolean returns TRUE if exists or made or FALSE on failure.
 */

function mkdir_recursive($pathname, $mode)
{
    is_dir(dirname($pathname)) || mkdir_recursive(dirname($pathname), $mode);
    return is_dir($pathname) || @mkdir($pathname, $mode);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
<?php 
test();
function test(){
    $root_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $directory_name = 'testDir';
    if (!file_exists($root_path.'/'.$directory_name)) {
        if(mkdir($root_path.'/'.$directory_name, 0777, true)){
            print "Directory created successfully.";
        }else{
            print "Error in creating Directory.";
        }
    }else{
        print "Directory already exists.";
    }
}
?>
```